# Creating a vibration in a non-activity class?

Tags: android, vibration

I am trying create a vibration for my game(Android), basically I want a vibration to start when a collision happens, but I can't create it because the class in which my level is running is not an activity class and I don't know ho to proceed, what should I do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

But your class that wants to create it should be called from an activity right? Then there is no problem to proceed like a vibration done in Activity Class:

```
public function vibrate(Context context){
    // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(context);

    // Vibrate for 300 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(300);
}
```

Comment: My activity class calls the Loading Screen, then it calls the MainMenu screen and from that the GameScreen, when I tried to create a vibrator in the game screen I get this "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type GameScreen".

Comment: You should pass the Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE as a parameter of your method that needs it.

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example of what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: It gives me the same error, actually you gave me an idea, LoadingScreen MainMenu and GameScreen extend a Screen interface, I tried extending the screen interface with activity and when I created the vibrator in my gamescreen class it didn't give any errors,however now when I run the game it gives me a runtime error,something like this:
04-19 20:14:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19930): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-44713
04-19 20:14:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19930): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: That it's because you are calling something on your working thread that must be called in the main UI thread. Try debugging step by step to see where it crashes.

Comment: I created a new class with a static method that vibrates, but at run time it says NullPointerException here is the part of the class with the method:
http://pastebin.com/mrbmMXaC

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
public void startVibrate(Context context, int repeat) {
    vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    int dot = 200;          // Length of a Morse Code "dot" in milliseconds
    int dash = 500;         // Length of a Morse Code "dash" in milliseconds
    int short_gap = 200;    // Length of Gap Between dots/dashes
    int medium_gap = 500;   // Length of Gap Between Letters
    int long_gap = 1000;    // Length of Gap Between Words
    long[] pattern = {
            0,  // Start immediately
            dot, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, medium_gap,    // S
            dash, short_gap, dash, short_gap, dash, medium_gap, // O
            dot, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, long_gap       // S
    };
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, repeat);
    //vibrator.vibrate(10000);
}
```