# Why does the device vibrate from an Activity, but not from within a Class (file)?

Tags: java, android, android-vibration

I want my app to vibrate the device using my app's custom vibration pattern. I can do this from MainActivity, or any Activity, but I don't know why it isn't working from within a Java class (SmsReceiver.java).

I thought that if I use `...context.getApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);` it would get the MainActivity context and thus would be kind of like I was in the MainActivity and it would vibrate. But nope. It doesn't vibrate from the Receiver class.

How do I vibrate the phone from the SmsReceiver.java class?

SmsReceiver.java:

```
package com.app.name.app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if (bundle != null) {
                // get sms objects
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                if (pdus.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                // large message might be broken into many
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                }

                String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                Log.d("SNDR", sender);
                String message = sb.toString();

                // prevent any other broadcast receivers from receiving broadcast
                abortBroadcast();
                if(!message.isEmpty())
                {
                    if(message == "!")
                    {
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.cancel();

                        long[] longs = { 0, 75, 15, 100, 15, 100, 15, 75, 15 };
                        v.vibrate(longs, -1);
                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java, onButtonClick:

```
switch(id)
{
    case R.id.action_search:
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        long[] longs = { 0, 75, 15, 100, 15, 100, 15, 75, 15 };
        v.vibrate(longs, -1);
        break;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        break;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173322/creating-a-vibration-in-a-non-activity-class) related question does not solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, and I didn't mention that because I thought it was the normal way. So when that didn't work I tried it the way that's shown in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's any restriction on using the `Vibrator` service from a `BroadcastReceiver`. I think your problem has to do with your `String` comparison. You should be using `String#equals()` to test for `String` equality, not `==`.

```
if(message.equals("!"))
```